Boon of the Night Spirit when leaving dim light
Do I stay invisible until I take my action/bonus action/reaction, even if I leave the dim light? The feat reads:

Merge with Shadows. While within Dim Light or Darkness, you can give yourself the Invisible condition as a Bonus Action. The condition ends on you immediately after you take an action, a Bonus Action, or a Reaction.

It says nothing about losing invisibility when leaving the dim light, but from my perspective, by all means, it should end when I leave the dim light.

You benefit from the invisible condition until you take an action, a bonus action or a reaction.
The rules for conditions's duration are the following:

A condition lasts either for a duration specified by the effect that imposed the condition or until the condition is countered (the Prone condition is countered by standing up, for example).

The Epic Boon specifies that the condition ends immediately after one takes
an action, a Bonus Action, or a Reaction: nowhere is stated that leaving the Dim Light or Darkness area ends it.
Being within the Dim Light or Darkness allows one to start the Invisible condition: if the condition was linked to being in such kind of areas, it would have stated so. Compare with the other benefit granted by this boon:

Shadowy Form. While within Dim Light or Darkness, you have Resistance to all damage except Psychic and Radiant.

The resistance is applied only while being in Dim Light or Darkness.

Yeah, that's what I was thinking. Originally I thought that that was quite powerful, but then I realized: you need to be level 19 or higher for this feat, of course it's going to be powerful
